# Does EM wave lose energy in air?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, air, attenuation

Light is EM wave.

As it travels through vacuum, it does not lose energy but I am wondering if it travels in air, just imagine light in your home. Before it reaches your eye, it has to travel through air. Do not air molecules interfere with it and make it lose some of its energy ? If not, why not?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation answer your question? In short, yes, air attenuates/weakens light and other EM waves.

Comment: What I am mostly wondering is on the internet it is said EM waves dont lose energy while they travel. My question is does this relate to vacuum only and not in air ?

Comment: EM waves can loose energy due to many reasons,- scattering, absorption, relativistic Doppler shift. Even in vacuum photons which reach us from deep space are extended in wavelength (hence loose frequency/energy) due to expanding space. BTW, for the same reason cosmic microwave background photons continue to loose energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, EM waves are attenuated in air. The attenuation is small and negligible for many applications, but some applications, such as transmission of data using microwaves or even optical light over land can be negatively impacted by this attenuation.

Comment: Thanks. So the only place em wave does not lose tiny bit of energy is in vacuum only right ?

Comment: @Chemistry yes.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It would also depend on the wavelength you are considering. For instance, it is well known that at THz frequencies there is atmospheric absorption due to water vapour. Also, oxygen takes part in this attenuation and studies show some spectral dips in the THz regime. I am sharing a paper so you can see it for yourself.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022407313001702